# Rename Sequelize migrations table

Tags: node.js, migration, sequelize.js

I'm using [migrations](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/migrations/) in [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/) with CLI commands, e.g.: `sequelize db:migrate`.

How do I configure Sequelize to use different table name for migrations, e.g. `migrations` instead of `SequelizeMeta`?

Looks like [it could be configured](https://github.com/sequelize/umzug#options-1) via `umzug`, however, I don't know hot to pass this configuration to it using Sequelize's CLI.

Answer (score 3):

Fast forward ( 3 years ), but will be useful:

In config.json or config.js ( depends if you need [dynamic configuration](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/migrations.html#dynamic-configuration) ) add option

```
"migrationStorageTableName": "your_name_for_migration_tables" ( Default: SequelizeMeta )
```

alongside default ones

```
  "development": {
     "username": "root",
     "password": null,
     "database": "database_development",
     "host": "127.0.0.1",
     "dialect": "mysql", }
```

For detailed explanation read the [manual](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/migrations.html#migration-storage).

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Umzug [Sequelize storage options](https://github.com/sequelize/umzug/blob/master/src/storages/SequelizeStorage.js#L7-L39) are:

```
/**
 * @param {Object} [options]
 * @param {Object} [options.]
 * @param {Object} [options.sequelize] - configured instance of Sequelize.
 * @param {Object} [options.model] - Sequelize model - must have column name
 * matching "columnName" option.
 * @param {String} [options.modelName='SequelizeMeta'] - name of the model
 * to create if "model" option is not supplied.
 * @param {String} [options.tableName=modelName] - name of the table to create
 * if "model" option is not supplied.
 * @param {String} [options.schema=schema] - name of the schema to create
 * the table under, defaults to undefined.
 * @param {String} [options.columnName='name'] - name of the table column
 * holding migration name.
 * @param {String} [options.columnType=Sequelize.STRING] - type of the column.
 * For utf8mb4 charsets under InnoDB, you may need to set this <= 190.
 * @param {Boolean} [options.timestamps=false] - option to add timestamps to the model table
 */
```

So, you can pass `tableName` option at Umzug initialization time:

```
import Umzug from 'umzug';

const  umzug = new Umzug({
  storage: 'sequelize',
  storageOptions: {
    sequelize, // your initialized sequelize instance
    tableName: 'sequelize_migrations', // your custom migrations table name
  },
  ... // other settings
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't know, also spent a bit of time to figure it out.
Had to look through the tests of [umzug](https://github.com/sequelize/umzug) to understand what is happening.

Settings are as close to `sequelize-cli` as possible (had to dive deeper into `sequilize-cli` too), so you won't have to change migrations files.

I'm using TypeScript, I hope that it won't be a problem to understand how it works.

```
import * as Sequelize from "sequelize";
import * as Umzug from "umzug";

let dbConfig = {
    "dialect": "sqlite",
    "storage": "test.db",
    "seederStorage": "sequelize"
},
let sequelize = new Sequelize(dbName, username, password, dbConfig);

let umzug = new Umzug({
    storage: "sequelize",
    storageOptions: {
        sequelize: sequelize,
        // tableName: "migrations"
        tableName: "SequelizeData" // default table name for sequelize-cli `seeder`
    },
    migrations: {
        path: "built/migrations/seeder",
        params: [sequelize.getQueryInterface(), sequelize.Sequelize] // arguments for `up` and `down`
    }
});

...

umzug.up();
umzug.down();

...
```

migration file:

```
module.exports = {
    up: function (queryInterface: QueryInterface, sequelize: DataTypes) {
        return queryInterface.bulkInsert("some_table", {});
    },
    down: function (queryInterface: QueryInterface, sequelize: DataTypes) {
        return queryInterface.bulkDelete("some_table", {});
    }
};
```